# What is the probability for choosing the right numbers in this table?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a table which has 28 columms and 28 rows like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7RtH.png

To choose the "right" number in this table, let say we can refer to this result:

```
result = 2,15,23,26,38,40,49,49,50,51,57,61,63,64,66,66,67,71,74,75,79,81,81,82,86,95,99
```

Please note that `result` has 27 numbers. No more nor less.

The "right" number is, let say `Col(0,2)`=63. `Result` also has 63, so `Col(0,2)` is "right". So "choosing the right number" is "detecting which cell in the table that has the same number that is in the `result`". I hope that is clear enough.

I also did the statistics, put all the columns into account and have the following list of "right" numbers:

Choosing by columns:

```
col0: 63 15 51 81 61 23

col1: 95 23 81 81 61 75

col2: 67 75 75 71

col3: 81 23 79 15 15 23 15

col4: 95 61 23 57 75 61 15 71 57

col5: 79 15 95 67 79 79 75 51 57

col6: 63 67 15 75 99 79 57

col7: 51 15 49 67 51 75 81 71

col8: 99 61 15 49

col9: 15 23 75 51 61 67 23

col10: 63 23 95 79 67 99

col11: 15 79 51 61 23 67

col12: 67 15 63 71 51 99 15 49 51 99 23 63

col13: 81 95 79

col14: 75 51 63 63 61 63 67 15 15

col15: 95 81 63 71 75 99 57 15

col16: 23 23

col17: 51 23 49 57 61 71

col18: 23 51 95 63 15 81 81 61 99 79

col19: 23 71 99 95

col20: 61 79 23 81 61 95 49 63

col21: 49 79 63 15 67 81 67 63 51

col22: 75 95 15 61 79 75 49 81 49

col23: 71 49 79 23 99 49 51

col24: 63 51 23 67 49 49

col25: 75 15 79 57 95

col26: 95 99 79 57 99 51 51 79 75 95 61

col27: 71 63 75 15 63 67 79 79 75
```

As you can see, there is the maximum-right column (the column which has the most "right" numbers) and minimum-right column (the column which has the least "right" numbers). Correspondingly they are `col12` and `col16`

Choosing by rows:

```
row2: 63 79 63 99 75 23 49

row3: 81 63 15 95 51 51 75

row4: 67 15 15 23 51 23 75

row5: 23 95 81 95

row6: 95 23 51 67 95 95 71

row7: 79 15 63 63 49

row8: 95 61 79 63

row9: 49 15 49 15 23 99

row10: 23 61 95 63 63 15 79 79 61

row11: 15 79 63 23 23

row12: 51 75 71 81 51 79

row13: 81 67 67 79 51 61 81 63 23 57 71

row14: 81 23 67 51 61 67 61 81 63 23 57 79 99 67 63

row15: 57 75 75 95 67 71 71 75 49 15

row16: 15 15 51 23 75 61 81 61 49 79 99

row17: 61 81 75 81 51 15 99 51

row18: 61 61 95 15 81 57 75

row19: 15 99 61 95 49 51

row20: 71 75 15 49 49 79 15

row21: 23 75 15 79 99 49 99 23 71 99 67 63

row22: 61 79 79 67 79 63 51 49 67

row23: 75 71 75 15 23 99 51 57 81 79

row24: 23 51 67 99 67 95 75 79

row25: 57 57 49 15 63 95

row26: 15 57 23 79 15 51 61 75

row27: 71 63

row28:
```

In which maximum-right row is `row14` and minimum-right row is `row27`

So, let say I do not know the `result` and do not have those list (they will be shown after I finish choosing). I only have the table. And I have to choose one or more numbers in the table that have as much as "right" number possible. The probability may be around `2/28` and `15/28`. Because my way of choosing is based on columns and rows.

Maybe you know a better way of choosing which has a higher probability.

So what is the probability for choosing the "right" numbers according to you? If it outside of `(2/28; 15/28)`, I mean higher than `15/28`, what is your way of choosing?

Comment: Sorry but it is impossible to understand your question. Try to express it in a compressed form.

Comment: Sorry. So, given the table. `Result` will be given after choosing. Choose one or more numbers from the table. How much is the probability of choosing the right number(s)? (A right number of the table is the same as one of the numbers in the `result`)

Comment: You have a *set* named "Result" of numbers. A *matching cell* (not "right number" - that is an incredibly bad description) is one which contains a number from the set. And you want pick the columns or rows which have the *most* or *least* matching cells.

Comment: However, even with the corrected terminology, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You want to pick the best and worst matching rows or columns *without knowing the numbers in Result*? On what basis? The only thing I can see you can do to improve your odds over picking at random would be to identify the rows/columns that have the most unique values to increase the chance of matches, and the rows/columns with the fewest unique values to decrease the chance of matches. Unless you know something about how result is chosen, there is nothing else to do.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry, because English is not my mother tongue. Actually, this is a multi-round quiz, and the table above is one of them. I did the statistics with many tables and temporarily have a conclusion: If choosing based on random rows and columns, the probability is in range (2/28; 15/28). The table above is actually not the original table. The original is even less the chance of matching. To make the table above, I multiplied the original to 2, to 3 and add 3 (to all cells, and remove the numbers in the hundred position), and saw that the matching has been improved.

Comment: But, that's all I can figure out (because I also multiplied-to and add-with other numbers, the probability will not be higher than 15/28). This is my limit. There may be some more method that I cannot figure out myself. So two (or more) brains is better than one, with that probability 2/28 to 15/28 tested through every table. The next table, and all the tables there are should have the same probability, if I keep choosing on through every table, is the maximum chance of matching will be 15/28? Meaning no matter how hard I try, I can only pick out half of the matching number, at most?